# Jquery Slider with content loader

Tags: jquery

Hi Guys 
I'm new to JQuery I was just wondering if any one could help me with that problem i nearly achieved what i wanted. 
Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/meyson/EsfXD/

So i have that slider with different tabs. Once user clicks on sliders it moves and swaps tabs. In each of the tabs there are gif loader which kinda imitates loading data (I know its strange but that is what i need to do). That loader only works when page is first time loaded, however i need to execute that loader every time new tab is loaded. So when i move from fist to second tab i would like that loading function to be executed and when i move back to tab one i would like that function to be executed again. I hope that make sense.

Many thanks for help with that.

Comment: I don't see any sort of loading animation when switching tabs.

Comment: i think that should work now, i agree animation is maybe too much to call it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the setTimeout(revealContent, 7250); in the select function (which is called on every slide). Further you are now hiding and showing all loaders but you only want to hide and show the one on the clicked page.

Ok, try this which displays the loaders for 2s on every tab switch... if you also want to hide the content first you should try to figure it out ourself.

```
$(function() {
 $("#tabs").tabs({
     select: function(event, ui) {
         $("#slider").slider("value", ui.index);
         revealContent(ui.index+1);             
     }
 });
 $("#slider").slider({
     min: 0,
     max: $("#tabs").tabs("length") - 1,
     slide: function(event, ui) {
         $("#tabs").tabs("select", ui.value);
         $(this).slide(); // fixes the animation
     },
     animate: true
 });


});


 jQuery(function() {
     revealContent(1);
 });

 function revealContent(id) {
     jQuery('#tabs-'+id+' .loadingGifs').show();
     setTimeout(function(){
         jQuery('#tabs-'+id+' .loadingGifs').hide();    
     }, 2000);     
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, would you be king enough to show me how this could be implemented in the code please, sorry as i mentioned above i'm beginner with jquery

Comment: ok I'm calling setTimeout function within slider however not it doesnt want to swap those div's see here http://jsfiddle.net/meyson/stQYe/